# Rust return object in collection with lifetime shorter than the collection itself

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am trying to essentially create a cache of heap-allocated objects with a `HashSet`. The idea is I have a struct which wraps a byte-reference, and when creating a new object, I check if the bytes it wraps are already in use, and if so, re-use the existing heap-allocated bytes.

```
#![feature(new_uninit)]

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ObjStorageT {
    /// Tab for unique storage
    pub tab_: std::collections::HashSet<Box<[u8]>>,
}

impl ObjStorageT {
    /// Create new byte storage
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return ObjStorageT {
            tab_: std::collections::HashSet::<Box<[u8]>>::new(),
        };
    }

    /// Get existing bytes from storage or new new bytes if they don't exist.
    pub fn getBytes(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        if !self.tab_.contains(bytes) {
            let mut new_bytes_base: Box<[std::mem::MaybeUninit<u8>]> =
                Box::new_uninit_slice(bytes.len());
            for i in 0..bytes.len() {
                new_bytes_base[i].write(bytes[i]);
            }
            self.tab_.insert(unsafe { new_bytes_base.assume_init() });
        }
        let existing_bytes: Option<&Box<[u8]>> = self.tab_.get(bytes);
        return existing_bytes.unwrap();
    }
}

/// Get storage for ir constants
pub fn globalStorage() -> &'static mut ObjStorageT {
    static mut GLBStorageOnce: bool = false;
    static mut GLBStorage: std::mem::MaybeUninit<ObjStorageT> = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
    #[allow(unsafe_code)]
    unsafe {
        if !GLBStorageOnce {
            GLBStorageOnce = true;
            GLBStorage.write(ObjStorageT::new());
        }
        return GLBStorage.assume_init_mut();
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct BytesWrapperT<'a> {
    bytes_: &'a [u8],
}

impl BytesWrapperT<'_> {
    /// New new constant w/ global obj storage
    pub fn new<'a, 'b>(store_: &'a mut ObjStorageT, bytes: &[u8]) -> BytesWrapperT<'a> {
        let new_bytes = store_.getBytes(bytes);
        return BytesWrapperT { bytes_: new_bytes };
    }

    /// New new constant w/ global obj storage
    pub fn newGlobal<'g>(bytes: &[u8]) -> BytesWrapperT<'g> {
        let new_bytes = globalStorage().getBytes(bytes);
        return BytesWrapperT { bytes_: new_bytes };
    }

    pub fn isZeros(self) -> bool {
        return self.bytes_.into_iter().all(|x| *x == 0);
    }
}

// Doesn't Compile
fn main() {
    let mut store: ObjStorageT = ObjStorageT::new();
    let mut arr0: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];

    let bw0 = BytesWrapperT::new(&mut store, &arr0);
    assert!(bw0.isZeros());

    arr0[0] = 1;
    let bw1 = BytesWrapperT::new(&mut store, &arr0);
    assert!(!bw1.isZeros());
    assert!(bw0.isZeros());
}
```

The issue is this code doesn't compile because `&mut store` is being borrowed by both `bw0` and `bw1` i.e:

```
74 |     let bw0 = BytesWrapperT::new(&mut store, &arr0);
   |                                  ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
78 |     let bw1 = BytesWrapperT::new(&mut store, &arr0);
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
79 |     assert!(!bw1.isZeros());
80 |     assert!(bw0.isZeros());
   |             --- first borrow later used here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e953d8e244dd52419b8ef791f2943854)

I think the issue is that in `BytesWrapperT::new` the returned lifetime of `BytesWrapperT<'a>` is the same as that of the incoming store `store_: &'a mut ObjStorageT` but I can't figure out how to get it so that I can return a lifetime only as long as the new `ByteWrapperT` and not require it to be as long as the `ObjStorageT` (only  req is not last longer than the `ObjStorageT`).

I tried changing implementation to:

```
impl<'a, 'b> BytesWrapperT<'b> {
    /// New new constant w/ global obj storage
    pub fn new(store_: &'a mut ObjStorageT, bytes: &[u8]) -> BytesWrapperT<'b> {
        let new_bytes = store_.getBytes(bytes);
        return BytesWrapperT { bytes_: new_bytes };
    }
// ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c195fafe9b1cf878f93b5609ae7f482) but that doesn't work because the the return lifetime of `ObjStorageT::getBytes` doesn't match.

I was able to get the code to compile using global static variables (see [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=122b3803471ede0daf35028d14be07b1)) but truthfully I don't really understand, from the perspective of lifetimes, what that can be work but the one that takes `&mut store_` argument doesn't.

Any help in

1. Figuring out how to configure the lifetimes s.t I can reuse `&mut store` and
2. Why the static version works at all

Would be appreciated.

Thank you!

edit:
Forgive the style warnings :(

Comment: (Unrelated, but) May I ask why are you using `camelCase` for functions instead of the standard `snake_case`?

Comment: No reason. Just like it to all be consistent personally.

Comment: Then at least allow the lints.

Comment: You're using `unsafe` _extremely_ freely. You can replace all of this unsafe with safe equivalents, that should be the same speed or faster. Try it :)

Comment: @ChayminFriedman Not sure how to do the allocation part w.o `unsafe`, but yeah the global static part can be done w.o `unsafe`. Really was just a hack to test with a static-global to help understand the lifetime issue.

Comment: Hint: `Box<[u8]>` implements `From<&[u8]>`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, sorry I'm quite new to rust.

Comment: Is it more appropriate to leave codes uneditted or to update links/example w/ safer code (also can fix the function names)?

Comment: Also, your initialization function is unsound because of concurrent access. Why don't you use std's `OnceLock<Mutex>`?

Comment: And about the style too, yes, you can choose whatever style you want, but I strongly recommend to train yourself to the official Rust style. Otherwise, others will have very hard time reading your code.

Comment: re:"Also, your initialization function is unsound because of concurrent access. Why don't you use std's OnceLock<Mutex>?" This application is never going to parallel. But again the static global was just to try to understand what was going on with the lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do what you want using unsafe code, but it is likely that you don't *need* it. You can go with a safe equivalent that is almost the same performance wise.

Instead of `Box<[u8]>`, just store `Arc<[u8]>` (or `Rc<[u8]>`). It'll only be few bytes for each allocation and few cycles more for refcount increments, but it lets you do it all safely:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ObjStorageT {
    /// Tab for unique storage
    pub tab_: HashSet<Arc<[u8]>>,
}

impl ObjStorageT {
    /// Create new byte storage
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return ObjStorageT {
            tab_: HashSet::new(),
        };
    }

    /// Get existing bytes from storage or new new bytes if they don't exist.
    pub fn getBytes(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Arc<[u8]> {
        match self.tab_.get(bytes) {
            Some(existing_bytes) => Arc::clone(existing_bytes),
            None => {
                let bytes = bytes.into();
                self.tab_.insert(Arc::clone(&bytes));
                bytes
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct BytesWrapperT {
    bytes_: Arc<[u8]>,
}

impl BytesWrapperT {
    /// New new constant w/ global obj storage
    pub fn new(store_: &mut ObjStorageT, bytes: &[u8]) -> BytesWrapperT {
        let new_bytes = store_.getBytes(bytes);
        return BytesWrapperT { bytes_: new_bytes };
    }

    /// New new constant w/ global obj storage
    pub fn newGlobal(bytes: &[u8]) -> BytesWrapperT {
        let new_bytes = globalStorage().getBytes(bytes);
        return BytesWrapperT { bytes_: new_bytes };
    }

    pub fn isZeros(self) -> bool {
        return self.bytes_.into_iter().all(|x| *x == 0);
    }
}
```

It is not possible, however, to change the bytes you insert. I'll argue it's a good property: they're shared, and you don't want someone to change your bytes underneath your back. If you really want, you can wrap them in a `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Comment: Thank you. Think this probably makes the most sense, but any chance you can also point me towards the unsafe tech that solves the lifetime issues?

Comment: @Noah If you're a beginner in Rust, you don't need it. If you don't know whether you need it, you don't need it. If you will need it, you'll know. If you only want to learn, the magic trick is to make `getBytes()` take `&self`. It is similar to an arena, except that most arena implementations yield `&mut T` on allocation and never reuse the same allocation, and you want yo yield `&T` (`&[u8]`) (otherwise it is unsound to reuse) and search in existing records.

Comment: Fair enough. Why does the static version work but the argument one doesn't? It seems both should suffer from the same problem of holding a reference to a store which outlives?

Comment: What do you mean by both versions?

Comment: [This version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021) is able to compile. Its basically the same code but instead of using `store` thats local to the function, it uses a mutable global static `store`.

Comment: @Noah You linked to the homepage of the playground. But if I guess correctly what you meant, it is because Rust does not track lifetime with `static mut` at all. Part of the reason it's unsafe.

Comment: Ahh sorry: [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8bb3f274941654e7063650e5e24dd251)

Comment: I see. So by using static I just disabling the pass that found the error, not doing anything that actually resolved it.

Comment: @Noah Something like this, yes. Not entirely disabling, it's just for the `static mut` they aren't tracked.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ended up using `Rc`, Any I guess will switch to `Arc` if I parallelize.